# Divide the values of two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I have two dictionaries with the same keys and I would like to do division on the values to update or create a new dictionary, keeping the keys intact, with the quotient as the new value for each of the keys.

```
d1 = { 'a':12 , 'b':10 , 'c':2 }
d2 = { 'a':0 , 'c':2 , 'b':5}
d3 = d2 / d1

d3 = { 'a':0 , 'b':0.5 , 'c':1 }
```

Aside from iterating through the key, value pairs and creating ordered lists of the values, then dividing, I'm not sure how to do this. I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 27):

Using viewkeys (python2.7):

```
{k: float(d2[k])/d1[k] for k in d1.viewkeys() & d2}
```

Same in python 3 (where we can drop the `float()` call altogether):

```
{k: d2[k]/d1[k] for k in d1.keys() & d2}
```

Yes, I am using a key intersection here; if you are absolutely sure your keys are the same in both, just use `d2`:

```
{k: float(d2[k])/d1[k] for k in d2}
```

And to be complete, In Python 2.6 and before you'll have to use a `dict()` constructor with a generator expression to achieve the same:

```
dict((k, float(d2[k])/d1[k]) for k in d2)
```

which generates a sequence of key-value tuples.

Comment: key intersection is not necessary, OP states that the 2 dicts have the same keys

Comment: @jamylak: better safe than sorry? :-P

Comment: Just noting that the `float` call isn't necessary in Python 3 and that `d1.keys() & d2.keys()` can be written as `d1.keys() & d2`.

Comment: @vaultah: ah, yes, of course. The `d2.viewkeys()` call is also not needed.

Answer (score 7):

```
d1 = { 'a':12 , 'b':10 , 'c':2 }
d2 = { 'a':0 , 'c':2 , 'b':5}
d3={x:float(d2[x])/d1[x] for x in d1}
print d3
```

**output:**

```
{'a': 0.0, 'c': 1.0, 'b': 0.5}
```

Comment: @Thrustmaster: it's called a dict comprehension; introduced in python 2.7: [PEP 274](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

Answer (score 6):

This works for all pythons, I would however recommend the solution by [@MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840128/1219006) if have Py 2.7+

```
>>> d1 = { 'a':12 , 'b':10 , 'c':2 }
>>> d2 = { 'a':0 , 'c':2 , 'b':5}
>>> d3 = dict((k, float(d2[k]) / d1[k]) for k in d2)
>>> d3
{'a': 0.0, 'c': 1.0, 'b': 0.5}
```

Answer (score 1):

in 3.2 you use the .keys() method and the .get(key). 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: `.get(key)` returns None if the key isn't defined. Though it always will be if you loop over `.keys()`, this does mean `.get(key)` is slower than just plain item access (`d1[key]`).