# Dividing values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, division

I am trying to divide the values stored in two dictionaries. There was a similar answer to this question found here: [Divide the values of two dictionaries in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840111/divide-the-values-of-two-dictionaries-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

However, every time I try to make that solution work, I get a syntax error.

Here's my code:

```
avg_length = {x:float(STRlen[x])/count[x] for x in STRlen}
```

My error:

```
avg_length = {x:float(STRlen[x])/count[x] for x in STRlen}
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Divide the values of two dictionaries in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840111/divide-the-values-of-two-dictionaries-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Python 2.7 or newer for the syntax to work.

On older versions, use:

```
avg_length = dict((x, float(STRlen[x])/count[x]) for x in STRlen)
```

Note that if you had read the [answer by jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11840138/100297), you would already have known this. :-)

Comment: I see--that's what was meant by "all pythons"
My bad! Thank you!